# Prevent event from bubbling up the dom tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have a card component as follows

```
<div
      onClick={e => {
        console.log("DEMAND CARD CLICKED");
        if (isSelectionActive) {
          setSelected();
        }
      }}
>  
      <DemandCardFooter
        demandId={id}
        totalBooked={totalBooked}
        totalDemand={totalDemand}
      />    
</div>
```

This is what `<DemandCardFooter/>` looks like:

```
<div className="vt-card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline px-3">
      <DemandSelector demandId={demandId} />
      <p className="lead font-weight-bold mb-0">
        <span className="text-success">{totalBooked}</span> / {totalDemand}{" "}
        <small className="text-muted font-weight-normal">Units.</small>
      </p>
</div>
```

And finally this is how `<DemandSelector/>` looks like:

```
const DemandSelector = ({ demandId }) => {
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useRowSelector({
    path: "demands",
    payload: { id: demandId }
  });
  return (
    <Checkbox
      checked={isChecked ? true : false}
      onClick={e => {
        console.log("CHECKBOX CLICKED");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
        setChecked();
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

My problem is when i click the checkbox both the checkbox's `onClick` and card's `onClick` are triggered, is there any way i can restrict the callback to the lowest level?

[image]

Comment: What issue are you getting with `e.stopPropagation();` I can see that you are using this in your code. It should prevent the event from propagation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after a while. The solution was to put `stopPropogation()` in the DOM element encasing `<DemandSelector/>`

So This code worked

```
 <div
      className="vt-card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline px-3"
      onClick={e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }}
    >
      <DemandSelector demandId={demandId} />
      <p className="lead font-weight-bold mb-0">
        <span className="text-success">{totalBooked}</span> / {totalDemand}{" "}
        <small className="text-muted font-weight-normal">Units.</small>
      </p>
    </div>
```

Also don't forget to put it all the way down

```
const DemandSelector = ({ demandId }) => {
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useRowSelector({
    path: "demands",
    payload: { id: demandId }
  });

  return (
    <Checkbox
      checked={isChecked ? true : false}
      onClick={e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        setChecked();
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not issue with event bubbling, the issue is with event capturing phase.

The event is stopped from bubbling up with `e.stopPropagation();` which you are using in your code. But the event capturing is not prevented in the parent event.

You could prevent it by adding `e.stopPropagation();` in the parent event.

```
<div
      onClick={e => {
         e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("DEMAND CARD CLICKED");
        if (isSelectionActive) {
          setSelected();
        }
      }}
    >
      <DemandCardFooter
        demandId={id}
        totalBooked={totalBooked}
        totalDemand={totalDemand}
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried this and it does not work, I am getting the same issue

Comment: Which react version are you using ? It could be a bug.

Comment: I am using  React v16.12.0